# Implementing Java Comparator

Tags: java, implementation, priority-queue, comparator

I am trying to write an algorithm which utilizes a min-priority queue, so I looked around on google and found the PriorityQueue. It seems that in order to use it, though, I am going to need to tell it how I want it to prioritize, and that the way to do this is with a comparator (I want to compare specific data fields of my "Node1" objects). More googling presented the idea of creating a new comparator which implements Comparator but overrides the compare method. What I am trying is this (and other variations of it as well):

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class distComparator implements Comparator {

    @Override
    public int compare(Node1 x, Node1 y){
        if(x.dist<y.dist){
            return -1;
        }
        if(x.dist>y.dist){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The compiler protests on several grounds, one of which is that I haven't over-ridden the comparator class (which it says is abstract)

> error: distComparator is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Object,Object) in Comparator

I have switched it to say "compare(object x, object y)", which takes care of that issue. At this point though the compiler complains that it can't find the "dist" variable in x or y--which makes sense, since they are part of my Node1 class, not the Object class.

So how is this supposed to work? It should have type `Object`, apparently, but then how do I direct it to the correct variable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to implement `Comparator<Node1>`:

```
public class distComparator implements Comparator<Node1> {
                                                 ^^^^^^^
```

Without this, you are implementing `Comparator<Object>`, which isn't what you want (it can be made to work, but isn't worth the hassle).

The rest of the code in your question is fine, provided `Node1` has an accessible member called `dist`.

Note that if you are using Java 7, the entire body of the method can be replaced with

```
return Integer.compare(x.dist, y.dist);
```

(replace `Integer` with `Double` etc, depending on the type of `Node1.dist`.)

Comment: You could also write `return x.dist - y.dist`

Comment: @Polygnome: Depending on the ranges involved this may or may not work for integers, but is a complete non-starter for floating-point values.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see [here (the JSE Comparator JavaDoc page)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html),
the `Comparator` interface has a generic "parameter"
describing the type
for which this comparator is designed.
The [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is similar.

So,
if you create a `PriorityQueue<Node1>`,
you can create a `Comparator<Node1>` as follows:

```
public class distComparator implements Comparator<Node1> {    
    @Override
    public int compare(Node1 x, Node1 y){
        return x.dist - y.dist;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `<>` instead of `[]`